# Auto copy for javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to find a code that will automatically copy a text when you click on it with no button.

What I mean by this:

Say we have a symbol and this symbol is "T". When you click on T it should copy "T" to your clipboard. I do not want a button either.

Comment: What did you try? What happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Obsidian Age, this is not a duplicate. Please reread what I said. I don't want to copy it manually. I want it to be automatic.

Comment: Define "*automatic*". Should it happen as you type? Then just call the JavaScript method `onkeyup`. Automation is only an additional `1%` of the above duplicate. And yes, this has to be done in JavaScript; it cannot be done in raw HTML.

Comment: Automatic?  Yet your question says "when you **click** on it".  The copy is triggered by a user event.  You respond to that event.  Just how much more automatic do you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can copy selected text to the clipboard using `document.execCommand("copy")` (part of the [Clipboard API](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/)), and you can detect when the user selects text by listening for the `selectionchange` event (part of the [Selection API](https://www.w3.org/TR/selection-api/)).

However, these features don't work together. At least in Chrome, the `copy` command only works when a script is running as the direct result of a user interaction, like a click or keypress -- and `selectionchange` events don't seem to count as user interactions. So you may be out of luck, unless there's something I've overlooked.